# Classes or their classes

Tags: word-choice

Which sounds natural "their classes" or "classes"?

"Russian students finish classes at three o'clock."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me both sound quite natural.

> Russian students finish classes at three o'clock.

effectively includes an implied "their" so the meaning is the same as

> Russian students finish their classes at three o'clock.

It could also be rephrased as:

> In Russia students finish [their] classes at three o'clock.

This allows for the possibility that students who are Russian but studying elsewhere finish at a different time, and implies that students who are not Russian but **are** studying in Russia also finish at three. Again "their" may be included or omited. That is simply a matter of style, with no change in the meaning.

Comment: In fact, there are more written instances of [*We finish **class** at (five o'clock)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+finish+class+at%22) than [*We finish **our classes** at...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+finish+our+classes+at%22) OR [*We finish **classes** at...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+finish+classes+at%22). And I don't think using the singular necessarily implies the speaker only attends a single class - singular ***class*** is fine here even if the speaker attends half-a-dozen different classes in his normal school day.

Comment: Do native speakers say "after classes" or "after their classes students go home".